# IE 11 Enhanced Protection Mode to access cookies

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, cookies, add-on, bho

According to this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx, Enhanced Protected Mode doesn't offer an API to access cookies.

Recently, my code to get cookies, that uses InternetGetCookieEx and works in IE 10 and earlier, stopped working in Win 8.1/IE 11.

Is there an API or other way to read and write cookies in IE 11?

I would like to read session cookies and write a persistent cookie.

My code is in C++ but I am open to using other languages.

Thanks!

Comment: I should mention that the program that uses InternetGetCookieEx runs outside of the IE process and reads/writes cookies in DWebBrowserEvents2 event handlers.  The InternetGetCookieEx API works for most IE versions but apparently due to enhanced protection mode, it is no longer reliable in IE 11 so I need to find another approach.

Comment: I am thinking of using IHTMLDocument2 get_cookie & set_cookie.  Has anyone had problems accessing cookies in this way?

Comment: IHTMLDocument2 get_cookie works for me even with Win10 and IE11 while InternetGetCookieEx and IEGetProtectedModeCookie does not and both always returns error 259.